# Custom domain for end-point?

Tags: clickatell

I would like to customize the end-point domain for SMS Platform, is it possible?
Is it possible to use a CNAME to whitelabel the end-point?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean white-label the API, or the communicator type screen?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Clickatell caters for that, but you could use your own domain and set up an html page which uses the clickatell API to send the messages. It would require some development though.